# Error [ImportError: No module named 'django'] while trying to integrate apache2 with Django 1.11

Tags: django, apache2

I really need help with this as I've been trying to get the bottom of it for a while. I'm trying to get Django to use the apache2 server.However, when I try to log to the apache page I get :

---

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.1.1 Port 80

---

I have copied my version(s) output from the ubuntu 1404LTS

---

Python 3.6.0+ (default, Feb  4 2017, 11:11:33) 
[GCC 4.9.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

---

> > > django.VERSION
> > >       (1, 11, 4, 'final', 0)
> > >
> > > ---

dpkg -l | grep wsgi
ii  libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3                               3.4-4ubuntu2.1.14.04.2                              amd64        Python 3 WSGI adapter module for Apache

---

When I open the logs, I see the below:

---

[Tue Feb 27 02:32:43.409875 2018] [:error] [pid 3211:tid 140311519147904] AssertionError:
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:44.388403 2018] [:warn] [pid 3567:tid 139906080114560] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.0.
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:44.388477 2018] [:warn] [pid 3567:tid 139906080114560] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.4.3.
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:44.389364 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3567:tid 139906080114560] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/3.4.3 co$
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:44.389393 2018] [core:notice] [pid 3567:tid 139906080114560] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:56.461421 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905975727872] [remote 127.0.0.1:10860] mod_wsgi (pid=3570): Target WSGI script '/ho$
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:56.461514 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905975727872] [remote 127.0.0.1:10860] mod_wsgi (pid=3570): Exception occurred proc$
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:56.474525 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905975727872] [remote 127.0.0.1:10860] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:56.476070 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905975727872] [remote 127.0.0.1:10860]   File "/home/serverio/server.io_Tools/server.i$
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:56.476112 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905975727872] [remote 127.0.0.1:10860]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_ap$
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:56.476194 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905975727872] [remote 127.0.0.1:10860] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:59.026294 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905858123520] [remote 127.0.0.1:30046] mod_wsgi (pid=3570): Target WSGI script '/ho$
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:59.026362 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905858123520] [remote 127.0.0.1:30046] mod_wsgi (pid=3570): Exception occurred proc$
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:59.026402 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905858123520] [remote 127.0.0.1:30046] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:59.026461 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905858123520] [remote 127.0.0.1:30046]   File "/home/serverio/server.io_Tools/server.i$
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:59.026480 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905858123520] [remote 127.0.0.1:30046]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_ap$
[Tue Feb 27 02:32:59.026507 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905858123520] [remote 127.0.0.1:30046] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[Tue Feb 27 02:33:07.853432 2018] [:error] [pid 3570:tid 139905975727872] [remote 127.0.0.1:30046] mod_wsgi (pid=3570): Target WSGI script '/ho$

---

And this is my 000-default configurations for the apache server:

---

ServerName serverio

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

Alias /static /home/serverio/server.io_Tools/server.io/mysite/userManager/static
    <Directory /home/serverio/server.io_Tools/server.io/mysite/userManager/static>
       Require all granted
     </Directory>

<Directory /home/serverio/server.io_Tools/server.io/mysite/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess serverio python-path=/home/serverio/server.io_Tools/server.io:/home/serverio/server.io_Tools/server.io/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup serverio
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/serverio/server.io_Tools/server.io/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

____________________________________________________________________________
```

when I tried the steps that Yka advised I get the errors:
   when I run  the configure command, I get the following error:__checking for 
    ___________________________________________________________________________
apxs2... no
checking for apxs... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for prctl... yes
checking Apache version... ./configure: line 2765: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2765: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2766: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2769: /: Is a directory

./configure: line 2964: apxs: command not found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile

---

when I try to issue sudo make, i get :

---

apxs -c -I/usr/include/python3.6m -DNDEBUG  -Wc,-g -Wc,-O2  src/server/mod_wsgi.c src/server/wsgi_*.c -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m  -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/bin/sh: 1: apxs: not found
make: *** [src/server/mod_wsgi.la] Error 127

YKH, check out the new error i'm getting

---

when i run :sudo apt-get install apache2-dev  it get the below errror as soon as i enter sudo make.

```
virtual-machine:~/Downloads/mod_wsgi-4.5.24$ sudo make 
/usr/bin/apxs2 -c -I/usr/include/python3.6m -DNDEBUG  -Wc,-g -Wc,-O2  src/server/mod_wsgi.c src/server/wsgi_*.c -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m  -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile --tag=disable-static x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -std=gnu99 -prefer-pic -pipe -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE  -pthread  -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1.0   -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include -g -O2 -I/usr/include/python3.6m -DNDEBUG  -c -o src/server/mod_wsgi.lo src/server/mod_wsgi.c && touch src/server/mod_wsgi.slo
In file included from src/server/mod_wsgi.c:22:0:
src/server/wsgi_python.h:24:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [src/server/mod_wsgi.la] Error 1


I also tried this another machine, this time on ubuntu 16LTS and get a similar 
error message as shown below:
_________________________________________________________


  2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 65824:tid 140243591341952] AH00491: caught
SIGTERM, shutting down [Tue Feb 27 14:49:42.462678 2018]
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 1366:tid 140394775304064] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18
(Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations [Tue Feb 27
14:49:42.463290 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1366:tid 140394775304064]
AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2' [Tue Feb 27 14:55:49.361004
2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1366:tid 140394775304064] AH00491: caught
SIGTERM, shutting down [Tue Feb 27 14:55:50.444530 2018] [wsgi:warn]
[pid 2393:tid 139752168679296] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Tue Feb 27 14:55:50.444616 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 2393:tid
139752168679296] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2. [Tue Feb 27
14:55:50.445196 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2393:tid 139752168679296]
AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured
-- resuming normal operations [Tue Feb 27 14:55:50.445223 2018]
[core:notice] [pid 2393:tid 139752168679296] AH00094: Command line:
'/usr/sbin/apache2' [Tue Feb 27 16:26:53.178835 2018] [mpm_event:notice]
[pid 2393:tid 139752168679296] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 27 16:26:54.191342 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2972:tid
139914716534656] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be see by paths in the messages, your mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 3.4. The code you are trying to run for Django is python3.6.

You need to reinstall mod_wsgi compiled against Python 3.X version you want to use.

Note also that you cannot use mod_wsgi compiled for one Python version with a Python virtual environment for a different version. The mod_wsgi must be compiled for the same version.

> [mod_wsgi issue239](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/239)

Go here download latest [mod_wsgi](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases) ,copy it to your server, run:

```
    tar xvfz mod_wsgi-X.Y.tar.gz
    cd mod_wsgi-X.Y/
    sudo ./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.6
    sudo make
    sudo make install 

    sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load
    LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so # write this to wsgi.load file

    sudo a2enmod wsgi 
    sudo service apache2 restart
```

The `mod_wsgi` can't run `django` project with `python3.4` and `python3.6` at same time,if you have some project run with `python3.4` before,you need update it's virtual environment to `python3.6` too, as `django2.0`(which will stop maintain at 2019/03) is the last version support `python3.4`,update all project to `python3.6` is a good choice,that all!

---

On ubuntu14.04、Apache 2.4.7、Django 2.0.2

This is how i install python3.6:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6 python3.6-dev python3.6-venv
```

and apache2:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-dev
```

create virtual environment with:

```
python3.6 -m venv environment
```

Comment: Hi i tried that and got the following error when I got the sudo make section________________________________________________________:sudo make
apxs -c -I/usr/include/python3.6m -DNDEBUG  -Wc,-g -Wc,-O2  src/server/mod_wsgi.c src/server/wsgi_*.c -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m  -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/bin/sh: 1: apxs: not found

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install apache2-dev` then run it again.

Comment: check `/usr/bin/python3.6` file exist?

Comment: on Ubuntu 14LTS i do not see it there but I actually went ahead and built an ubuntu 16LTS which has python 3.5 as the base python3 version . I then installed python 3.6 using sudo apt-get install python3.6. After that i created a virtuanENV using virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6  serverio. I installed Mod_wsgi using the ./configure  and make method but  still I failed and got the error message above.

Comment: Hi, I have doing a bit of novice reading. Do you think using the 'WSGIPythonHome'  command will resolve this problem for me?

Comment: Answer updated,i install `python3.6-dev`,this may needed.

Comment: on ubuntu see log `Compiled for Python/3.5.1+. mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.`,the same python version for mod_wsgi compiled and django project used is not enough,it must be same install.

Comment: I notice `WSGIPythonHome` too before,but it's not helpful.Notice `python3.6-dev` and `apache2-dev` is needed,you need reinstall your `python3.6`.

Comment: A patch level difference in Python version is not an issue, only major/minor version difference. See the documentation at http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#python-patch-level-mismatch

Comment: Thanks for correcting,but i still don't know why `apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536` happen.(By the way,i have read a lot of articles you wrote,it helps me a lot,thanks for this again.)

Comment: Graham, thank you for helping.  I read that document but  I didn't fully understand as I'm still learning. The document stays: 'This would generally not be a problem provided that both versions of Python were originally installed with the --enable-shared option supplied to ‘configure’. '   . Because  I did not use the ./configure and Make method to install python; I just used the  command 'sudo apt-get install python3.6'. Does that mean the version mismatch is still an issue ? Does using the sudo command automatically  configure python  to use '--enable-shared'

Comment: Hello YKH,  you have been a massive help to me.  I finally see the  light 
 at the end of the dark tunnel.   I had to rebuild a new server (Ubuntu 16 LTS) as I crashed the old one. I finally served up my first page using apache2. My God! what pain and and sleepless nights this has caused me :-)    I still have some minor issue though. let me know if you can guide me on this( mostly permission issues and Admin site) or If you are busy I'll keep trying and raise a new topic if I can't figure it out.   Thank  you so much .  I could not up-mark  your answer as I'm too new to the site. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.614457662@qq.com is my email,feel free to contact me.